# retag and edit question links are disabled

Tags: support, edits

Some times when I want to edit or retag some question I find that the links are disabled for that question, but I can still edit/retag other questions, is there any reason for that ?

Here is a screen shot of the disabled link (just to get what I mean better)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to hover over the links? The tooltip will probably say why it's disabled.

Comment: No I didn't, when I went back to check, the links were enabled again

Comment: When in doubt, hover. =)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it is not duplicate, in the user the user could not edit any question, but I could edit other questions, also this one was only disabled temporary so I guess the answer of Raghav Sood is reflecting the actual thing, also hovering in important to know, I will try it next time :)

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae The highest voted answer lists all the reasons why you would be prevented from editing a question.

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae As you will see when this will be closed, the banner says "This question already has an answer here" linking to the other post, and in this case it's 100% true. The question might be different but the answer there applies here just fine. :)

Comment: Thanks @ShaWizDowArd for the hint :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens whenever there is a pending edit waiting for approval on that question. The links are disabled to prevent conflicting edits from being made.

When you have enough reputation (2000, as pointed out by Sha Wiz Dow Ard in the comments) to review edits, it'll become a link like `edit(1)`, and by clicking it you'll be shown a dialog where you can approve, reject or improve the pending edit. Something like in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: True, the required rep is 2000

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you. Updated answer with required rep.