# Disable 'Edit' option in new review queues if you have too many pending suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I was reviewing First Answers on a site where I don't have full edit privileges. I chose the 'Edit' option and clicked Submit. Only after editing the post and trying to submit the suggested edit, I was notified that I had already too many pending suggested edits.

Can this detection be applied immediately after clicking 'Submit', just like the 'edit' link underneath the post already does? (Or alternatively, disable the Edit option entirely.)

[image: review queue item where "Edit" is selected and the "too many pending edits" error message is displayed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369161 ;)

Comment: @41686d6564 seriously? I posted so many answers to that announcement, I didn't remember ...

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292974/282094   and a bit of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170220/282094 - it's supposed (used) to be disabled.

Comment: @Rob This question is not asking why the error message is showing up. It's asking for the edit *review* option to not be selectable if one has too many pending edits. It's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica That question states that requests filed after September 10, 2021, should be posted as new questions rather than as answers there.

Comment: @Son, that's not the point being made.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog this request has already been filed (by Glorfindel)