# What is the correct procedure for reviewing when you have too many edits pending?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I was recently working through some of the **Late Answers** review queue on Stack Overflow, but had a question regarding what to do when a user has "too many pending edits" and is unable to take the proper action regarding a review task.

This may share some similarity to this question regarding [Disabling the Edit Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370543/disable-edit-option-in-new-review-queues-if-you-have-too-many-pending-suggeste) when a user has too many pending edits.

The situation is this: I am below the reputation requirement for automatic edits and frequently reach the 5 edits pending threshold. As a side note, I really enjoy editing and am the top editor on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) so it is pretty easy for me to hit this number. This complicates things, however, when I am working through the review queues.

For example, when I am looking through the **Late Answers** queue, frequently the **edit** option is the appropriate action to take for a given question (perhaps to fix link formatting, add an image, or markdown formatting). However, since I already have 5 edits pending, it only lets me click to make the edit but freezes when I click to submit it. This makes sense - I have reached the maximum 5 edits - but it does not change the fact that clicking **edit** and making some changes was the appropriate review action for this particular answer.

My question then is - what am I supposed to do when **edit** is the correct review action, but I am unable to edit the question/answer? So far, I have just been skipping the question and in some cases just bookmarking it to try to edit later. This seems like kind of a waste though. Is this the appropriate action to take in theses cases or is there some other procedure that I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 7):

You are already doing the best thing you can, within the system, and even more besides.

1. If there is no other appropriate action available, **Skip** the review item. This avoids the decision of which wrong thing to do. Don't do the wrong thing just to say you completed the review when you couldn't do the right thing. It's okay to skip reviews that you can't complete correctly, and much more preferable to the alternatives.
2. If you feel so inclined, save the question for later. You can still make edits to a post outside of review! So wait until you get an "edit slot" back, then make the edits you intended.

You might find that someone else makes decent edits while you are waiting, and you don't need to make any. That's okay too, as long as the question gets the improvement it needs.

You can also comment to describe what changes you would make if you could. Someone else might get to it, otherwise you have some "notes in the margin" to remind yourself later. It's easier than writing a whole unnecessary draft, and keeps everything in one place.

Answer (score 5):

The correct procedure is to gain enough reputation to [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), it isn't that hard ... Just kidding, and thanks for helping out in the review queues! I encounter the same situation now and then on other sites in the network, so I sympathize.

> So far, I have just been skipping the question and in some cases just bookmarking it to try to edit later.

That's certainly a good option, but if you keep on suggesting edits from the review queues, you won't get to the point where you have free slots to suggest edits on those posts.

You can leave a comment stating what you'd like to change, and hope the author (or somebody else with >2k reputation) reads it and edits the post accordingly. The author can even *learn* from your comment and make better posts in the future. You can follow the post so that you're notified of any edits, after which you could consider removing your comment.

On smaller sites where there aren't many active reviewers in the queues, you can try to encourage more people to review with a Meta question, like I did on Web Applications: [Please help reviewing suggested edits!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4733/136642) I don't think that would work on Stack Overflow though, it's simply too big to have any effect.